# Java TCP split packets

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration TCP connections. From the Serializer implementation i write some bytes directly to the given OutputStream.

The first byte seems to be sent on its own (in it's own TCP packet, which is by the way reported malformed by wireshark) and then the remaining bytes in the next packet.

Changing the first two bytes to be written in one call (two byte long array) causes these two bytes to be sent in a seperate packet (not malformed) and the remaning in the next packet. This outcome is reproducible.

Is this something I can (or should) affect? It is causing problems on the reading end, because that equipment apparently expects the entire message to be contained in a single TCP packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this something I can (or should) affect? It is causing problems on the reading end, because that equipment apparently expects the entire message to be contained in a single TCP packet.

Then the author of this application has no idea of TCP. TCP is a stream based and not a packet based protocol. This means that a single write can result into multiple packets on the wire or multiple writes can result in a single packet.

> ...which is by the way reported malformed by wireshark...

If you capture the packets on the sender system you probably see the effects of offloading the checksum computing to the network card. In this case wireshark will report the checksums wrong. If you capture the packets in-between or on the receiving end you should see the correct checksum because the network card on the senders machine calculated the checksum before forwarding the packet.

Comment: Definitely. However the OP can mitigate his problem to some extent by interposing a BufferedOutputStream, and flushing before he goes to read the response.

Comment: While you're correct, it's not helping the OP, isn't it? As long as he can't fix the receiver side this answer isn't bringing him one step closer to a solution (except that he now knows where the checksum error might be coming from).

Comment: @DarkDust There *is* no way to help the OP, other than the possible mitigation I mentioned. If you think differently, post your answer.

Comment: @EJP: I think your comment is the answer (or a similar solution; the point is to have _one_ write call to the socket, however that's done in Java). So IMHO there _is_ a way to help the OP but I lack the Java skills to post an answer. But I think that Steffen's answer itself is not helping the OP solve his problem even though his explanations are useful.

Comment: @DarkDust It's a *possible* answer. It isn't guaranteed to work. I haven't said otherwise. Steffen's answer is perfectly correct. It's a byte stream; the receiver can't make any assumptions about packetisation; and the sender can't really control it.

Comment: The questioner knows that the other application expects all data within a single read. Therefore I assumed that he spoke to the author of the application or has access to the source code. In this case the answer should help him to either fix the application himself or have the right arguments to make the original author fix it. Workarounds might be possible, but are not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. That confirms what I knew about the situation before. Buffering the data manually for a single send call from java to the native OS code, might help. But it is not exactly a bullet proof solution.